# Difference in the `glVertexAttribPointer` function in C and Java

Tags: java, opengl

When I look at the javadoc for the `glVertexAttribPointer` function, I see it is the "Entry point to C language function:

`void glVertexAttribPointer(GLuint index, GLint size, GLenum type, GLboolean normalized, GLsizei stride, const void * pointer)`.

The correspondance between arguments is mostly straigthforward except for the last parameter. The "C" version seems logical : data must be specified and a pointer is perfect for that. In the Java version, I'm much more confused because a `long` integer is expected...

Can anyone explain me how this `long` integer can represent a "C" pointer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The last parameter of [`glVertexAttribPointer`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glVertexAttribPointer.xhtml) has different meanings,  depending on the circumstances the function is used.
If no buffer object (zero) is bound to the `GL_ARRAY_BUFFER` target, then it is a pointer to the first component of the first generic vertex attribute in the array ([Legacy OpenGL](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Legacy_OpenGL)).
If an named buffer object is bound to the target `GL_ARRAY_BUFFER`, then is treated as a byte offset into the buffer object's data store (See [`glBindBuffer`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glBindBuffer.xhtml) and [Vertex Specification](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Vertex_Specification))